# Exporting to FBX stretches out bones

Tags: animation, export, unity

I have a rig I'm trying to animate, but when I export the animation to an FBX file, the bones get all stretched out.

It looks like the feet and hand bones are moving away from where they're supposed to be, but I'm new to blender and I can't for the like of me figure it out. Here's some pictures to show what's happening.

I'm trying to make animations for Unity. The animations look the same in the Windows 3D Model Viewer as they do in Unity, so I know it's not just a Windows issue.

Model in Blender: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjorS.jpg

Model through 3D Model Viewer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0j7eX.png

Comment: Please insert your images directly into your question rather than adding links to them. People reading your post are much more likely to answer a question where they can see the images rather than having to follow links to view them. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post It might also be helpful to include a link to your Blend file which you can do via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page to add the link to your question.